# Google drive api failed to list folder or download files from Shared with me before open them in browser once, though anyone have read access

Tags: python, google-drive-api, privileges

In **share with me**, I have a folder shared from someone, and the privilege shows everyone have read access.

With my python script developed using Google drive API, I can list some subfolders and download some files, but failed to list other subfolders (got []) or download other files (404 error), while everyone have read access to all subfolders and files.

The most confusing is that, after open the failed folders or preview the failed files in browser, the problems will be solved.

I have no idea what cause the problem, I have read https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list and https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get, try to change arguments of `files().list()` and `files().get()`, with no luck.

I also use the "Try it" API toolkit from the urls above, and get same result.

PS. I tested my script with some other shared folders and didnot encounter the problem.

I use API service with my Gmail account, register my Desktop App with Oauth2 credentials, just same as the code shown in quickstart: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python, and the share url I test is here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B59W0kcOXxj6UUdYUzRYOHE0R1E?resourcekey=0-JyYB6JeJHIBT3lFz4e5NzA&usp=sharing

```py
def download_folder(folders_todownload):
    dict_folder2pagetoken = {}
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
    while folders_todownload:
        folderid, folderpath = folders_todownload.pop()
        while True:
            PageToken, page = dict_folder2pagetoken.get(folderid, (None, 1))
            q = "'%s' in parents" % (folderid)
            file_metas = "id, name, mimeType, resourceKey, createdTime, modifiedTime, originalFilename, md5Checksum, size"
            try:
                results = service.files().list(q=q, supportsAllDrives=True, fields="nextPageToken, files(%s)" % (file_metas), pageSize=1000, pageToken=PageToken).execute()
                if "nextPageToken" in results:
                    dict_folder2pagetoken[folderid] = (results["nextPageToken"], page + 1)
                items = results.get('files', [])

                if not items:
                    # some folders is empty before open them in browser
                    logging.warning('No files found in %s.' % (folderpath))
                    break
                cnt_todownload = len([x["md5Checksum"] for x in items if "md5Checksum" in x])
                seq_todownload = 0
                for item in items:
                    taskpath = folderpath + '/' + item['name']
                    item["parent"] = folderpath
                    if item['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                        folders_todownload.append((item['id'], taskpath))
                    elif "md5Checksum" in item:
                        seq_todownload += 1
                        logging.info("(%s/%s) download %s" % (seq_todownload, cnt_todownload, taskpath.split("/")[-1]))
                        try:
                            request = service.files().get_media(fileId=item['id'], supportsAllDrives=True, acknowledgeAbuse=True)
                            # for test purpose, just download first 1k byte
                            request.headers["Range"] = "bytes={}-{}".format(0, 1024)
                            # some files response 404 before preview them in browser
                            response = request.execute()
                        except HttpError as e:
                            # some files response 404 before preview them in browser
                            logging.error("download failed, HTTP CODE %s" % (e.status_code))
                        except HttpLib2Error as e:
                            logging.error("download failed, HttpLib2Error %s" % (e))
                        except Exception as e:
                            logging.error("download failed, Exception %s" % (e))
                    line = ""
                    for k in ["id", "parent", "name", "mimeType", "resourceKey", "createdTime", "modifiedTime", "originalFilename", "md5Checksum", "size"]:
                        line += item.get(k, "-") + "\t"
                    line = line.rstrip("\t") + "\n"
                    codecs.open(file_output, "a", "utf-8").write(line)
            except HttpError as error:
                folders_todownload.append((folderid, folderpath))
                logging.error('An HTTP error occurred: %s' % (error))
            except Exception as e:
                time.sleep(1)
                folders_todownload.append((folderid, folderpath))
                logging.error('An error occurred: %s' % (e))
            if "nextPageToken" not in results:
                break
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or just an explanation of the parameters that you are using when doing the API call to see what could be wrong. I was trying to reproduce the issue from my end but was unable to do so. In addition to  that, are both Google Workspace accounts or just regular Gmail accounts?

Comment: Thank you for the remind, this is the first time I ask a question. I have added my code and share url, and I test with my Gmail account.

Comment: I test google drive API v2 and confirm same problem happens.

Comment: I see you mentioned that this gets fixed after you go to the web UI and just open the files. Is that the first time you open the files ever or can the issue be reproduced with files that you know for sure that you have opened before? I am asking because there is an expected behavior like this according to the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:~:text=Files%20shared%20with%20you%20are%20searchable%20as%20long%20as%20you%27ve%20opened%20them.).

Comment: It's the first time I open the folders or preview/download the files. I read this in the url "You can only search for files stored in My Drive. Files stored in folders shared with you won't appear in your search unless you add the folders to My Drive. ", the most weird thing is all folders/files are from a root folder in "Shared with me", not appear in My Drive, but content in folder A can be listed with list() method, but folder B listed as empty, some files in Folder C can be downloaded with get() method, while other files in Folder C response with 403/404 error.

Comment: What are the specific 403 or 404 error messages that you get? Have you also noted any specific behavior with the files?

Comment: The 403 error reason is `downloadQuotaExceeded` and 404 error reason is `notFound`, I didn't notice any particular features of those files.

Comment: Since there is no expected behavior that can explain the error messages here, and it is not possible to reproduce the exact same behavior. You also mentioned that this can get fixed by just opening the files from the Google Drive web UI, and that you can reproduce it by using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/) feature from the [Drive API's official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), I think that this could be related to a possible bug from the API.

Comment: I would recommend posting this in Google's public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) with all this information so that someone at Google can check if this is a bug and possibly get investigated.

Comment: I also think this may be a bug, and I will post it to issue tracker for help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add the `includeItemsFromAllDrives=True` argument to your `files().list` method:

```
results = service.files().list(q=q, supportsAllDrives=True,
                               includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, 
                               fields="nextPageToken, 
                               files(%s)" % (file_metas), 
                               pageSize=1000, 
                               pageToken=PageToken).execute()
```